# Different ways to say "hope to Learn"

Tags: phrasing

I am writing a study proposal broken into three sections. The third section will cover "what I hope to learn," which is not the greatest phrasing for a section. Alternative suggestions would be appreciated.

Document breakdown:

- Problem Statement
- Measurement
- What I Hope to Learn *<-- Need better phrasing*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say *learning expectations*, *learning aims*, or *learning goals*. If the context allows it, you can also drop the word *learning*.

Answer (score 3):

How about *What I hope to learn* - sorry, that's just my dislike of random capitalisation showing through ;)

Things that cross my mind, depending on what you're going to put in the section:

- Desired outcomes
- Hypotheses
- Expectations
- Introduction (this would require that the section be put at the beginning. When I write a paper or similar, what I hope to learn goes in there.)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

> What I *Expect* to Learn

Alternatively:

> Expected Outcomes